# Azure Active Directory B2C with Azure Front door auth response uses wrong domain

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-front-door

We are using Azure Active Directory B2C in combination with Azure Front door. When signing in with a password and username it works fine, but when signing in with a social provider it shows the wrong domain.

Before sign in:

[image]

After sign in with social provider (loading before continuing with, in this case localhost)

[image]

The difference here, is that before the sign-in we have login.timchermin.com/**login.timchermin.com** and after we have login.timchermin.com/**lokaalaybler.onmicrosoft.com**. I would prefer the onmicrosoft.com to also be login.timchermin.com.

I tried putting https://login.timchermin.com/login.timchermin.com/oauth2/authresp in the google cloud app setting. But this will give the following error.

[image]

(How) Can I make it so that my authresp also includes the domain in after the first / ?
I am also using custom policies, if that makes a difference.
The domain login.timchermin.com is also set as the primary domain.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have all redirect URLs registered properly in your social IDP. This is my configuration for the Facebook login. I also use Front Door with Azure AD B2C:

[image]

Redirect URL should be aligned with this pattern when using custom domain:

https://your-custom-domain/name-of-your-ad-b2c-tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

Comment: In the provided image you also have onmicrosoft.com instead of the tech-mind-factory-identity.org domain after login.tech...etc/ comes techmindfactoryidentity.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: You are right, apologize, I wrongly understood your initial question. Let me check with Product Group, I will get back as soon as possible.

Comment: All good, my explanation definitely could have been better! I appreciate the help.

Comment: I have sent the question about this topic - once I have any updates I will let you know!

Comment: @TimChermin I am getting back with the response. There is no option currently to fully replace "onmicrosoft.com" in the URL. You can either use tenant ID or "tenant-name.onmicorosft" in the URL. The FQDN in the URL can make use of the cname but the next portion of the URL is a tenant identifier and cannot be the cname.

Comment: Alright makes sense yeah, thanks for your response and time! I'll mark this as the answer.